# scrapy-splash error Connection refused #111 when running 2 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I use scrapy-splash v3. I have 4 scrapy and 4 scrapy-splash total 8 crawlers. They start at intervals of 3 hours once a day.

```
01:00 PM > crawler-splash1
04:00 PM > crawler-scrapy1
07:00 PM > crawler-splash2
...
```

About 40 hours (1.5 day) after the first crawler starts, the server crashes or splash fails like

> http://172.18.0.10:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

When I restart the server, the connection is fixed and it starts working normally up to 2 days again.

What could go wrong? Are the server properties low or another problem? I have no idea. I tried to get the log, but it is empty, no error in log. But I have to restart the server every day.

My vp server : 2 vCore(s) 2.4 GHz 8 GB RAM 40 GB SSD Linux

Edit
Docker:

```
docker run -d --restart always --net pabedanetwork --ip 172.18.0.10 scrapinghub/splash -v3
```

Crawler

```
venv/bin/scrapy crawl crawler -a retailer=RetailerName
```

Comment: How to you run Splash, using Docker? And what log did you try to get?

Comment: Did you get into the splash container and see the log when it errors out? Also check `docker stats`. You should also see open files `sysctl fs.file-nr`. Also check if you can reach splash from the terminal or not

Comment: @TomášLinhart You can look edited for docker and crawler how to run.

Comment: @portakal I suspect some memory issues. Have a look at [FAQ](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-run-splash-in-production) section of documentation for production run options. And as suggested, check Docker log of course.